# WordPress Contact Form 7 not allowing exclusive selection for checkbox

Tags: wordpress, plugins, checkbox, contact-form-7

I have created a form in Contact Form 7 on WordPress which uses checkboxes. The checkboxes have the '[exclusive](http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/)' feature enabled so that you can only select one checkbox. I have ensured that the ordering of all the labels is correct because CF7 is very strict about this. But it's still allowing multiple selections. Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that your code follows the format:

```
[checkbox* label_name exclusive "option_1" "option_2" "option_3"]
```

Secondly, if the page has not fully loaded, and you make selections, you will still have the ability to select multiple checkboxes.

Try to remove any render-blocking javascripts and compress images to reduce this undesirable result.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem: **checkbox exclusive** also didn't work for me because of theme's CSS which didn't support it.

I also wanted non-mandatory radio selection for the form. I managed to overcome the problem by using one more "empty" field:

```
[radio choice label_first default:1 "" "Yes" "No"]
```

In CSS i added:

```
.wpcf7-list-item.first {
    display: none;
}
```

By selecting first "empty" choice, this effectively made radio non-required in validation.

Comment: in 2024 this no longer works